# Binary Search Tree inorder not working (python)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I've been messing around learning about objects and classes, and as I finally felt that I managed to wrap my head around how to construct a Binary Search Tree in python, I ran into an issue. Here's my code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self,current,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = node(value)
        else:
            if value < current.value:
                if current.left == None:
                    current.left = node(value)
                else:
                    self.add(current.left,value)
            if value > current.value:
                if current.right == None:
                    current.right = node(value)
                else:
                    self.add(current.right,value)

    def visit(self,node):
        print(node.value)

    def inorder(self,current):
        self.inorder(current.left)
        self.visit(current)
        self.inorder(current.right)

Tree = BST()
root = node(2)
Tree.root = root
Tree.add(Tree.root,7)

Tree.inorder(Tree.root)
```

after running the code, I got an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'`.
The error comes out of the inorder function, as apparently the value I'm inserting into the function is an object without a type.
as you can see, the root of the tree is a node object, so it should have the attribute "left" as per coded in the class. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with what I'm getting wrong.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I should note that I checked whether the root is a node with the `isinstance()`, function, and indeed it returned True.

Comment: So you're expecting *every* node in your tree to have both a left and right child node?  I hope you got a really good deal on the infinite amount of RAM you'd need to hold that tree...

Comment: Can you define a leaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you sould check current is not None before access its left and right.

```
  def inorder(self, current):
        if current:
            self.inorder(current.left)
            self.visit(current)
            self.inorder(current.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design has some problems.  The Tree should be the only object that knows about the root.  You shouldn't have to pass the root in.  Notice how this is simpler to use:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self,value,current=None):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = node(value)
            return

        if not current:
            current = self.root

        if value < current.value:
            if not current.left:
                current.left = node(value)
            else:
                self.add(value,current.left)
        else:
            if not current.right:
                current.right = node(value)
            else:
                self.add(value, current.right)

    def visit(self,node):
        print(node.value)

    def inorder(self,current=-1):
        if current == -1:
            current = self.root
        if not current:
            return
        self.inorder(current.left)
        self.visit(current)
        self.inorder(current.right)

Tree = BST()
Tree.add(2)
Tree.add(7)

Tree.inorder()
```